# Web3Py 'TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' error when executing a swap even if tokens spending have been approved

Tags: web3js, transactions, uniswap, web3.py

I tried to execute a swap using Web3py with the following function:

```
def swap(node, account_address, pvt_key, contract_address, contract_abi, action_type, amount_in, amount_out_min):
    #load USDC and WETH contracts. Those are the tokens we are going to use.
    weth_addr = web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619')
    usdc_addr = web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174')
    
    #connect to polygon node
    w3 = web3.Web3(web3.Web3.HTTPProvider(node))
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

    #This is the smart contract we will interact with to buy or sell the tokens.
    contract_addr = web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address.lower())
    contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_addr, abi=contract_abi)

    #set a correct gas price. This line of code could be surely optimized.
    gasPrice = w3.toWei(200, 'gwei')    
    
    amount_eth = int(amount_in*10**18)
        
    swap_path = [weth_addr, usdc_addr]
    amount_usdc = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount_eth, swap_path).call()[1]

        #execute swap
    min_amount_eth = int(amount_eth*0.97)
    deadline = int(time.time() + 60)
    function = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
      amount_eth,
      amount_usdc,
      swap_path,
      account_address,
      deadline
    )

    tx = function.buildTransaction({
      'from': account_address,
      'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address),
      'gasPrice': gasPrice,
    })
        
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, pvt_key)
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    print(tx_receipt)
```

But I get the error:

```
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED
```

So as suggested in [previous and similar questions][1] I approved spending of tokens as shown in the code following:

```
def swap(node, account_address, pvt_key, contract_address, contract_abi, action_type, amount_in, amount_out_min):
    #load USDC and WETH contracts. Those are the tokens we are going to use.
    weth_addr = web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619')
    usdc_addr = web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174')
    
    #connect to polygon node
    w3 = web3.Web3(web3.Web3.HTTPProvider(node))
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

    usdc_abi = ''''''
    usdc_contract = w3.eth.contract(weth_addr, abi=usdc_abi)
    weth_abi = ''''''
    weth_contract = w3.eth.contract(weth_addr, abi=weth_abi)


    #This is the smart contract we will interact with to buy or sell the tokens.
    contract_addr = web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address.lower())
    contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_addr, abi=contract_abi)

    #set a correct gas price. This line of code could be surely optimized.
    gasPrice = w3.toWei(200, 'gwei')    

    nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address)

    tx = usdc_contract.functions.approve(account_address, 1000000).buildTransaction({
        'from': account_address, 
        'nonce': nonce
        })
        
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, pvt_key)
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

    nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address)
    
    tx = weth_contract.functions.approve(account_address, 1000000).buildTransaction({
        'from': account_address, 
        'nonce': nonce
        })
        
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, pvt_key)
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    
    if action_type == 1 or action_type == 0:
        #we need to sell eth for usdc
        amount_eth = int(amount_in*10**18)
        
        swap_path = [weth_addr, usdc_addr]
        amount_usdc = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount_eth, swap_path).call()[1]

        #execute swap
        min_amount_eth = int(amount_eth*0.97)
        deadline = int(time.time() + 60)
        function = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
          amount_eth,
          amount_usdc,
          swap_path,
          account_address,
          deadline
        )

        tx = function.buildTransaction({
          'from': account_address,
          'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address),
          'gasPrice': gasPrice,
        })
        
        signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, pvt_key)
        tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
        tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
        print(tx_receipt)
```

But still getting the same error. Why transfer fails if I approve the token spending? Can't figure it out. Thank you.
[1]: [swap Tokens fails due to TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126477/swap-tokens-fails-due-to-transfer-from-failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because you approve the wrong address to spend tokens.

```
tx = usdc_contract.functions.approve(account_address, 1000000).buildTransaction({
    'from': account_address, 
    'nonce': nonce
    })
```

Instead of approving your own address, `account_address`, you should `approve` the `contract_address` to spend tokens on your behalf.

Change the approval on both **USDC** and **WETH** then your code should work.

Comment: finally works! thanls :)

Comment: Ehy I am sorry but I faced the same issue again. I am basically trying to sell USDC for WETH. The USDC spending has been approved several time but I got the same 'TRANSFER FROM FAILED' error. This is how code currently looks like: https://pastebin.com/1pFyCS9w . Can you please help me solving the issue?

Comment: can you open a new question, with more details about the error, it was working so you changed something?

Comment: i didn't change nothing, the wETH->USDC swap works well. But when I try to do the inverted swap (USDC->wETH) I get the same error (TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED') even if I approved the USDC transfer...